# Merge two coord_polar plots with common x axis and add x axis scale bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to create one plot where one circular coord_polar plot is inside the other, sharing the x axis but with different y axes. Additionally, I would like to add a scale bar to the inside of the circular plot representing the values of the x axis. Here is some test data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

test_data <- data.frame(start = c(1, 200, 450, 600, 800),
                        end = c(150, 440, 570, 780, 1200),
                        gene_name = c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4", "gene5"),
                        sample = 1,
                        gc = c(50.9, 49.8, 50.0, 51.0, 48.0)) %>%
  mutate(gene_length = end - start,
         pos = start + (gene_length/2)) %>%
  select(-gene_length)


p1 <- ggplot(test_data, aes(x = pos, y = gc)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-60, 52)) +
  coord_polar()


p2 <- ggplot(test_data, aes(x = pos, fill = gene_name)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = sample + 0.4)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, ymin = sample, ymax = sample + 0.8),
            color = "black",
            size = 0.01) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-10, 2)) +
  coord_polar()
```

p1

[image: p1 looks like this]

p2

[image: p2 looks like this]

What I want, is a plot that looks a bit like this (sorry for the terrible paint picture):
[image]

The black outside the main plot is the barplot represented by p1. I want the width of each bar to correspond in size to their respective element in the plot underneath. I have tried to merge these with tools such as cowplot or aplot, but neither seem to be able to put them inside one another. They rather put them over or under each other instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not put two geoms in one plot rather than trying to combine two plots? Note that to emphasise the differences in `gc`

I have started the gray regions at ymin = 47, but if you wanted you could drop these back to 0 and have the inner ring at a negative y value (since its y location seems to be arbitrary anyway).

```r
p1 <- ggplot(test_data, aes(x = pos, y = gc)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, ymin = 47, ymax = gc)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = sample + 0.4)) +
  geom_rect(aes(fill = gene_name, xmin = start, xmax = end, 
                ymin = sample, ymax = sample + 1),
            color = "black",
            size = 0.01) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(30, 52)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1250)) +
  coord_polar()
```

[image]